# Using Facebook Feed dialog URL to share is not updating the share count

Tags: facebook, dialog, share, feed

When I'm using the URL:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=&caption=Blah&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mypages.com%2Ffoobar%2Ffoo%3Fsource%3Dblah&name=foo+bar+foo&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fm411e3u2y.cloudfront.net%2Fscal00d000220%2F75db140db50acf1ee2d70ce7b2f06036.jpg&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com

It shares the Link with the correct link, image caption etc. but getting the count using

http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mypages.com%2Ffoobar%2Ffoo%3Fsource%3Dblah does not update the share count. Whereas the share count is updated if I copy/paste the same URL in facebook, or send a FB message or use the Like Button widget.

I'm trying to get the equivalent URL to turn the feed dialog url to Like URL.
Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but "share count" is from the share button that shows up with the like button.  Unfortunately making a custom one with the Fb.ui feed dialog isn't related or counted in this number, it's not "smart" like that.